# Reboot Google TV device through Anymote protocol?

Tags: google-tv, anymote

I am attempting to reboot a Google TV device remotely through the Anymote protocols. When I send CTRL+ALT+DEL through anymote, nothing happens. Is it possible to reboot Google TV devices remotely? Would it be possible to do by sending an Android Intent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is done purposely.

Normally, an app requires the permission: "android.intent.action.REBOOT" to successfully [reboot() the device](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#reboot%28java.lang.String%29). However, this permission can only be granted to system apps.

Allowing the device to reboot through the Anymote protocol would be a good example of [Privilege Escalation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation) where a system app is exposing this secure functionality to other apps without encforcing permissions.

So in response to your question: if the Anymote protocol did support rebooting it would be a security violation. And since it apparently doesn't, there is simply no way to reboot the TV without being a system app...

---

(Relevant aside: this is why it's always important that you review **your app** for potential security holes. If you request a permission and don't properly restrict access to it, you will be allowing other apps to exploit the flaw)

Comment: Agreed. This is one of the most frequently requested features for my app Able Remote, but I have not found a way to get Anymote to do a reboot. The physical remotes for Google TV that have ctrl+alt+del buttons do support rebooting.

Comment: Thanks guys for the input. This is exactly what I needed to know.

Leon: I assume its also not possible to reboot through your Able Remote for Google TV app running on the device itself?

Comment: Google TV apps cannot reboot the device due to the Android system restrictions.